# Oracle pivot transform to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, pivot

Short question, not so familiar with SQL server, but I have query with multiple aggregate in oracle sql server.

What is sql server equivalent query for multiple aggregate?

Oracle code:

```
[SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT d.loc_area,
                d.loc_rack,
                d.loc_height,
                d.loc_place,
                d.locvrc,
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) rn_pivot
           FROM (select locvrc,
                        SUBSTR(stoloc, 0, 2) loc_area,
                        SUBSTR(stoloc, 4, 2) loc_rack,
                        SUBSTR(stoloc, 6, 1) loc_place,
                        SUBSTR(stoloc, -2) loc_height
                   FROM locls) d)
  PIVOT (MAX(loc_height) AS EXT, MIN(locvrc) AS UNIQ FOR rn_pivot IN ('1' AS HEIGHT_1, '2' AS HEIGHT_2, '3' AS HEIGHT_3, '4' AS HEIGHT_4))
  ORDER BY LOC_AREA,
        LOC_RACK,
        LOC_PLACE]
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT d.loc_area,
                d.loc_rack,
                d.loc_height,
                d.loc_place,
                d.locvrc,
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) rn_pivot
           FROM (select locvrc,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 0, 2) loc_area,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 4, 2) loc_rack,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 6, 1) loc_place,
                        right(stoloc, 2) loc_height
                   FROM locls) d) A
  PIVOT (MAX(loc_height) FOR rn_pivot IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) P1
```

This is working fine, but I need the other aggregate |(MIN(locvrc)| also

Thank you in advance!

Br
Jan

/Edit,

Original table:

```
 Stoloc          locvrc
 5D-32A-00       699787
 5D-32A-10       439567
 5D-32A-20       429456
 5D-32A-30       122172
 5D-32B-00       328311
 5D-32B-10       247422
 5D-32B-20       133244
 5D-32B-30       464978
```

Table after substring:

```
loc_area loc_rack loc_place loc_height locvrc
 5D         32       A        00       699787
 5D         32       A        10       439567
 5D         32       A        20       429456
 5D         32       A        30       122172
 5D         32       B        00       328311
 5D         32       B        10       247422
 5D         32       B        20       133244
 5D         32       B        30       464978
```

What I have with Oracle is this:

```
loc_area loc_rack loc_place Height1 Uniq1   Height2 Uniq2   Height3 Uniq3 Height4 Unique4
5D       32        A         00     699787    10    439567    20    429456    30   122172
5D       32        B         00     328311    10    247422    20    133244    30   464978
```

So from the original table the stoloc will be cutted to different columns. After this in one line would be area, rack, place and with them in one row Height and locvrc. I have completed this in Oracle database, but dont know how to in SQl server. Doesnt need to be this kind of solution, any will do.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: More info added. Let me know if still lacking. -Jan

Comment: the column names within the example table do not conform to the column(`stoloc`) within the query

Comment: I know this is mess. I need to edit whole new post for make easier to help. Thought there would be simple solution like just "add this there" :)

Comment: @Jan00, updated and it should give the right result now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it odd but as per my knowledge this is how we can do it in `SQL server`.

We need to create another dimension for the same pivot columns by appending anything to it and put the same into `PIVOT` clause.

As you see I have added `1` and create another column to be used for `locvrc`

```
SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT d.loc_area,
                d.loc_rack,
                d.loc_height,
                d.loc_place,
                d.locvrc,
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) rn_pivot,
                cast(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) as varchar) + '1' rn_pivot_locvrc
           FROM (select locvrc,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 0, 2) loc_area,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 4, 2) loc_rack,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 6, 1) loc_place,
                        right(stoloc, 2) loc_height
                   FROM locls) d) A
  PIVOT (MAX(loc_height) FOR rn_pivot IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) P1
  PIVOT (MAX(locvrc) FOR rn_pivot_locvrc IN ([11],[21],[31],[41])) P2
```

P.S. My intention is to tell how you can `PIVOT` multiple columns abut unfortunately I certainly cannot validate the result set.

***EDIT:- Updated query with Op's actual data***

```
SELECT loc_area,loc_rack,loc_place
      ,max([1]) as height_1
      ,max([11]) as unique_1
      ,max([2]) as height_2
      ,max([21]) as unique_2
      ,max([3]) as height_3
      ,max([31]) as unique_3
      ,max([4]) as height_4
      ,max([41]) as unique_4
   FROM (SELECT d.loc_area,
                d.loc_rack,
                d.loc_height,
                d.loc_place,
                d.locvrc,
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) rn_pivot,
                cast(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) as varchar) + '1' rn_pivot_locvrc
           FROM (select locvrc,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 0, 2) loc_area,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 4, 2) loc_rack,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 6, 1) loc_place,
                        right(stoloc, 2) loc_height
                   FROM locls) d) A
  PIVOT (MAX(loc_height) FOR rn_pivot IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) P1
  PIVOT (MAX(locvrc) FOR rn_pivot_locvrc IN ([11],[21],[31],[41])) P2
group by loc_area,loc_rack,loc_place
```

**OR**

Using `aggregation` and `case` also it can be done,

```
SELECT loc_area,loc_rack,loc_place
      ,max(case when rn = 1 then loc_height end) height_1
      ,max(case when rn = 1 then locvrc end) unique_1
      ,max(case when rn = 2 then loc_height end) height_2
      ,max(case when rn = 2 then locvrc end) unique_2
      ,max(case when rn = 3 then loc_height end) height_3
      ,max(case when rn = 3 then locvrc end) unique_3
      ,max(case when rn = 4 then loc_height end) height_4
      ,max(case when rn = 4 then locvrc end) unique_4
   FROM (SELECT d.loc_area,
                d.loc_rack,
                d.loc_height,
                d.loc_place,
                d.locvrc,
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY d.loc_area, d.loc_rack, d.loc_place
                                   ORDER BY d.loc_height) rn
           FROM (select locvrc,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 0, 2) loc_area,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 4, 2) loc_rack,
                        SUBSTRing(stoloc, 6, 1) loc_place,
                        right(stoloc, 2) loc_height
                   FROM locls) d) A
group by loc_area,loc_rack,loc_place;
```

Comment: Yes you are right because you have other columns like `d.loc_area,d.loc_rack,d.loc_place` which you are not pivoting and it could impact the result set. and also I don't see `columnA ColumnB` in your original query

Comment: Thank you Sujitmohanty30 for the response. Was able to run the query, as you mentioned cant validate outcome and it is not exaclty correct. Going to right direction though.

Comment: @Jan00, I realized there was a mistake in the query which I just corrected which might be the cause but I am not sure

Comment: oh saw that myself and corrected also, but it was not that. but I will edit the post for better so it is easier to help, I know it is kind a mess with different column names in sample and in query.

Comment: I know now introducing the extra dimension also changes the output and to resolve it we need to aggregate final result. I have setup the query using the example you have sent. Could you have a look if it helps you. [db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de01b5ccca60347234d27f9d84a37eb7)

Comment: Wow, well that worked :) Thank you a ton! Is not neccessary, but is there way to make the order like 'height' 'unique' 'height''unique' insted heigh heigh uniq uniq? If it is simple, would appreciate but I can manage with this :) Thanks once again!

Comment: Updated. its just changing the columns names in the select clause.:) also added another way using case and aggregation

Comment: Oh of course :) well once again thank you for the help and have a wonderful weekend! -Jan